# How to get a plain text file version of a CP/M .BAS (M-BASIC) program?

Tags: basic, cp-m

I have an old game (STRTRK.BAS) from my dad's Kaypro 10 that I would like to convert to a plain text file. Basically, what I'm trying to do is get it onto a modern computer in plain text format so I can look at the source code and print it (hardcopy).

This game is accessible on the K10 itself, by starting up OBASIC (an older version of MBASIC, itself a platform independent implementation of BASIC-80).

The source code can be listed once loaded (again, on the actual machine).

My guess is the best route would be to find a CP/M emulator and install a version of CP/M, OBASIC, and the program onto it, but I actually haven't had any luck finding something that will run on a modern Windows 7 setup.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would converting it on the K10 and uploading it through a serial connection be an option?

Answer (score 12):

M-BASIC-80 knows the modifier "A" for the `SAVE` command - So, you should be able to create a readable ASCII file directly on the Kaypro computer by doing

```
LOAD "MYPROG.BAS"
LIST
SAVE "MYPROG.TXT",A
```

If you don't want to mess with old disks on a modern computer (I recommend you don't even start to look into this), your best bet would be to set up a serial RS-232 connection between the Kaypro and your modern machine - A suitable RS-232-USB dongle, a proper cable and a terminal program would suffice.

Comment: On Windows 10, I just downloaded & installed [RunCPM](https://sourceforge.net/projects/runcpm/) and then STRTRK.BAS as linked above, and started MBASIC and loaded the bas and it seems to run. I was also able to save it as ASCCI text.

Answer (score 7):

It wouldn't happen to be the one that the listing starts/ends like this, would it?

```
10 'EXPANDED APRIL 1977 BY W.A. BURTON
20 'PIRATED JAN. 1978 BY ZOSO
30 DIM G(8,8),S(8,8),K(3,3)
40 PRINTCHR$(26)
50 GOSUB 5460
   …
6350 IF Q8<0 OR Q8>S THEN GOTO 6340
6360 S=S-Q8:E=E+Q8:PRINT
6370 PRINT E;" UNITS OF ENERGY NOW - TRY AGAIN."
6380 RETURN 
6390 RESET
```

If so, there are *lots* of copies online, frinstance [STRTRK.BAS](http://www.classiccmp.org/cpmarchives/cpm/Software/rlee/K/KAYPRO/2X/BASICS/STRTRK.BAS). The program detokenizes and runs under both OBASIC.COM and MBASIC.COM.

Peter Schorn's [Altair 8800 simulator](https://schorn.ch/altair.html) site has emulators and disk images for many versions of CP/M. For instance, I downloaded the CP/M 2 distribution, unpacked it, moved the STRTRK.BAS file to the `cpm2` folder and started the emulator with:

```
altairz80 cpm2
```

After that, I was able to import the tokenized program with the command `R STRTRK.BAS`, then loaded MBASIC and the program could be loaded with `LOAD "STRTRK.BAS"`

Comment: Thanks for all the useful feedback. I ended up going the emulator route for now.  This worked well. I downloaded RunCPM and set up some folders for the disks and user areas. I then had to move a copy of OBASIC.COM and STRTRK.BAS to one of the user areas. With the emulator started, I was able to load the code using OBASIC (which detokenizes it) and then use the window's copy and paste functionality to move it over to Notepad to save it as a plain text file. Thanks to scruss, Michael Harvey, and tofro for all the useful information.

Comment: I found that STRTRK.BAS opened fine in MBASIC which is already on the "A" "disk" folder provided by the RunCPM guy, then, in MBASIC, I issued **SAVE "STRTRK.TXT", A** and I was able to open the resulting file directly in Notepad.

Comment: This is even better (saving with the A flag within the RunCPM emulator). My first attempt I was just copying the text directly from one window and pasting it into another, which resulted in a few spots in the text file that I had to manually edit. Saving within the emulator produces a clean text file. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Basic interpreters saved the code in a tokenised form to save space. I found this description of the format used by GW-Basic, a later version of MBASIC. I don't know if the file format changed between the versions, though.

http://justsolve.archiveteam.org/wiki/GW-BASIC_tokenized_file

It wouldn't be too hard to write a bit of code to convert from the byte-codes to text.

Comment: While this might seem a good idea at first, OBASIC/MBASIC and GW-BASIC use different token values. A tokenized CP/M BASIC program will often load into GW-BASIC, but listing it will show that it's riddled with syntax errors

Comment: @scruss I did suspect that might be the case. I couldn't find any info on the MBASIC tokenisation (and as better answers have been provided, it isn't really relevant).

Comment: fair point. I left the note here for future readers to suggest that this approach is a good one from a theoretical point of view, but needs some work for a real implementation. It's a perfectly good answer!